# Outgoing packages for port over 1024 dropped?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, zabbix, random

today i ran into a strange problem after setting up my Zabbix-Server and adding a Client.

As i tried to add my Client to the server, the server could not reach him.

After lots of troubleshooting i figured out that all packages which come into my server on a port higher than 1024 they are dropped.

For example:

I can connect via SSH:22 to my server but as soon as I set the port of SSH to 10050, 6969 etc. the connection cannot be established anymore.

I tried the same thing for the mysql server running on the server.

Unfortunatly i can't set the port of the Zabbex-Agent (Client of for the Server) below 1024. (Not bc of missing permissions, but bc the Agent is coded to not allow it).

IP-Table:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Suspected culprit is SELinux.
If you see in agent's log something like:

```
listener failed: bind() for [[-]:20051] failed: [13] Permission denied
```

Check current status with:

```
$ sestatus
```

Apply policy (for redhat):

```
$ yum install -y setroubleshoot-server selinux-policy-devel
$ semanage port -a -t zabbix_agent_port_t -p tcp 10050
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When I use that, i get this error:

`SELinux policy is not managed or store cannot be accessed.`